# Config issue with phpThumb on WAMP

Tags: php, image, wamp, phpthumb

I'm having trouble getting phpThumb to generate thumbnails on WAMP. The problem seems to be that the path to the source image is be being constructed incorrectly, as indicated by this debug info:

> DEBUG phpThumb: ResolveFilenameToAbsolute() prepending
>   $this->config_document_root
>   (C:\Projects\WordPressTest\Site\wp-content\plugins\yet-another-photoblog)
>   to $filename
>   (/wordpresstest/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/valentine-2-010.jpg)
>   resulting in ($AbsoluteFilename =
>   "C:\Projects\WordPressTest\Site\wp-content\plugins\yet-another-photoblog/wordpresstest/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/valentine-2-010.jpg")
>   in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1023

The correct path would be:

```
C:\Projects\WordPressTest\Site\wp-content\uploads\2009\02\valentine-2-010.jpg
```

I suspect it's something to do with the configuration of phpThumb. Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Apperently phpThumb doesn't like running under an alias on Windows. To get round it I ran my site in the document root instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced something similar with a project and found resolution in using all '/' -vs- '\'
(I don't know why or how... but fixed my issue)